# How to pass font name as string in pdf file with Java iText

Tags: pdf, fonts, itext, styles

I am generating pdf report with few inputs like font name, font size. I tried to create a font using below code.

```
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN,50.0f,Font.UNDERLINE,BaseColor.RED);
```

Here, how pass font name that is TIMES_ROMAN as a string?

Comment: not sure I understand the question. You want to write on a PDF with that Font definition, is that it?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. I am having a font as string (Ex. Calibri) which is coming from Excel sheet (XSSFWorkbook). I need to generate PDF file with that particular font name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way on how you can achieve the desired behavior with iText 7:

```
final PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontProgramFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.TIMES_ROMAN));

Style myStyle = new Style()
        .setFontSize(50)
        .setUnderline()
        .setFontColor(RED)
        .setFont(font);

try (final Document document = new Document(pdfDocument)) {
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!").addStyle(myStyle));
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!").setFont(font)
            .setFontSize(50)
            .setUnderline()
            .setFontColor(RED));
}
```

You can also define the font on a Document level (I'm showing [Style](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/Style.html) and directly on the Paragraph).

Comment: Don't forget to add that [this can easily be found on the web](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it5kb/examples/using-fonts).